# execve x86 - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, assembly, x86, shellcode, execve

I keep getting segmentation faults on this could anybody help me on this one, I am kind of new to ASM

```x86asm
global _start

section .text
_start:

push   dword 0x0068732F ; Push /sh
push   dword 0x6E69622F ; Push /bin
mov    eax, esp         ; Store Pointer To /bin/sh In EAX

push   dword 0x0000632D ; Push -c
mov    ebx, esp         ; Store Pointer To -c In EBX

push   dword 0x00000068 ; Push h
push   dword 0x7361622F ; Push /bas
push   dword 0x6E69622F ; Push /bin
mov    ecx, esp         ; Store Pointer To /bin/bash In ECX

push   dword 0x0        ; NULL 
push   ecx              ; Push /bin/bash Pointer
push   ebx              ; Push -c Pointer
push   eax              ; Push /bin/sh Pointer

mov    ebx, eax         ; Move /bin/sh Pointer To EAX
mov    ecx, esp         ; Store /bin/sh -c /bin/bash Pointer in ECX
xor    edx, edx         ; Store 0 In EDX

mov    al, 0xb          ; sys_execve
int    0x80             ; system call
```

I am trying to replicate the following

```C
char* Args[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/bash" };
    execve("/bin/sh", Args, NULL)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: On which line does your code raise the SEGV signal?  Your debugger should stop at that point and let you examine registers and memory to understand what's happening.

Comment: @TobySpeight Getting unknown line

Comment: @mewa if possible could you show me where because I am sure that I am doing as you said already

Comment: @0xDeMoN After those three pushes store esp into ecx. (I'll have to check it on a machine later though)

Comment: Note that the C code is wrong. The `Args` array needs a `NULL` at the end.

Comment: You *did* assemble with debugging information (`as -g`), yes?

Comment: @user3386109 yeah was typo when making question :D

Comment: @TobySpeight yeah i did it with -g

Comment: Umm yeah, except your assembly code matches that C code.

Comment: I haven't looked closely, but this type of issue is almost *always* called by a failure to properly align the stack.  Check your calling convention and verify that your stack is properly aligned before you make the call to the system.

Comment: Yeah was an old code copy will update now

Comment: @MichaelPetch why the `-s 30`?

Comment: Off the top of my head I thought it might print all the args, but come to think of it, it likely won't break down the argument array

Comment: @Jester any thing you see wrong there?

Comment: Have you run it through `strace` as Michael told you to?

Comment: @0xDeMoN Actually you just need NULL at the end of args and xor eax before doing int 80h

Comment: @mewa actually before the `mov    al, 0xb`. That only sets the low 8 bits, and the top 24 bits are probably nonzero so the syscall number gets clobbered. This is something strace or gdb would have shown.

Comment: @mewa thank you so much feel kind of dumb now and yeah need to use GDB and strace more... :D

Comment: @Jester Yes, obviously, that's what I meant ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the arguments need to be NULL terminated.

Also `mov al, 0xb` only sets the lower 8 bits of the (32 bit) `eax` register. 
Earlier on you also loaded an address from the stack into eax `mov eax, esp` and since the stack grows down, the value stored in `eax` will be much closer to `0xFFFFFFFF` that it is to `0`. When you later `mov al, 0xb` you only substitute the last `F` and `eax` needs to be *exactly* `0xb`.

Thus you need to either move the value to whole `eax` register or make sure its upper 24 bits are zeroed beforehand - for example by doing `xor eax, eax`.

```
global _start

section .text
_start:

push   dword 0x0068732F ; Push /sh
push   dword 0x6E69622F ; Push /bin
mov    eax, esp         ; Store Pointer To /bin/sh In EAX

push   dword 0x0000632D ; Push -c
mov    ebx, esp         ; Store Pointer To -c In EBX

push   dword 0x00000068 ; Push h
push   dword 0x7361622F ; Push /bas
push   dword 0x6E69622F ; Push /bin
mov    ecx, esp         ; Store Pointer To /bin/bash In ECX

push   0                ; <----- NULL args terminator
push   ecx              ; Push /bin/bash Pointer
push   ebx              ; Push -c Pointer
push   eax              ; Push /bin/sh Pointer

mov    ebx, eax         ; Move /bin/sh Pointer To EAX
mov    ecx, esp         ; Store /bin/sh -c /bin/bash Pointer in ECX
xor    edx, edx         ; Store 0 In EDX
;xor    eax, eax        ; <----- either xor eax, eax or mov into eax
mov    eax, 11          ; sys_execve
int    0x80             ; system call
```